# Как убрать валидацию имени пользователя ASP.NET MVC CORE?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3

Пытаюсь изменить пароль пользователя таким способом:

```
await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, code, editViewModel.Password);
```

- `user` - объект `ApplicationUser`,
- `code` - код сброса пароля, сгенерированный функцией `_userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync`,
- `editViewModel.Password` - строка, содержащая новый пароль.

При попытке изменить пароль результатом возвращается ошибка `User name 'Дмитрий' is invalid, can only contain letters or digits.` (Дмитрий - имя пользователя). Как отменить валидацию имени пользователя при изменении пароля?

Comment: Зачем вы в тело вопроса копируете ответ? Поставили галку на выбранном вами ответе -- и этого вполне достаточно.

Comment: @AK лично я далеко не сразу нашел где обнуляется это поле. Поэтому написал где обнулил я, чтобы если кто нибудь такой же слабый в программировании как я будет гуглить этот вопрос, ему не пришлось искать это место как мне.

Comment: Действительно, это не копия из принятого ответа. Прошу прощения за невнимательность и спасибо за пояснение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Допустимые символы в имени пользователя задаются в [`UserOptions.AllowedUserNameCharacters`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/UserOptions.cs). Вот значение по умолчанию:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the list of allowed characters in the username used to validate user names.
/// </summary>
/// <value>
/// The list of allowed characters in the username used to validate user names.
/// </value>
public string AllowedUserNameCharacters { get; set; } = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
```

[Судя по коду](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/UserValidator.cs), проверку можно отключить, сбросив эту строку на пустую или на `null`:

```
else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(manager.Options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters) &&
    userName.Any(c => !manager.Options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters.Contains(c)))
{
    errors.Add(Describer.InvalidUserName(userName));
}
```

Обнулить эту настройку можно в методе `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(opts =>
{
    opts.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = null;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло.

Comment: Зачем обнулять? Почему бы просто не добавить туда недостающие символы?

Comment: @tym32167 необходимо было убрать валидацию, а не изменить ее правила. Предложенное PashaPash решение позволяет полностью отменить валидацию имени пользователя.

Comment: @mirypoko да я не спорю с полезностью решения, мне просто было интересно узнать, зачем отменять валидацию :)

Comment: @tym32167 ну это стоит у топикастера спрашивать, а не у меня - я же написал, что эта строка задает допустимые символы. очевидно, что можно вписать туда те символы, которые нужно сделать допустимыми.

Comment: @PashaPash я бы перенес вопрос, но уже поздно это делать. В любом  случае, топикстартер уже ответил здесь.